# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android and junit test

Tags: android, junit, testcase

I saw that I'm not the only one having this problem but I don't find a correct answer.
I have an android project that I want to test. I create a junit test class for each class of my project.
My problem is when I run my test, I have the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/Context
```

This is my class test :

```
public class DevicesBDDTest extends TestCase {

    DevicesBDD bdd;

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    protected static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    protected static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Context ctx = mock(Context.class);
        final MaBaseSQLiteInterface mockMaBaseSQLite = mock(MaBaseSQLiteInterface.class);
        bdd = new DevicesBDD(ctx){
            @Override
            public MaBaseSQLiteInterface createMaBaseSQlite(Context context) {
                return mockMaBaseSQLite;
            }
        };
    }


    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void test() {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

My class DevicesBDD has needs an object Context, therefore I create a mock (with mockito). I tried with a object MockContext too, but it's doesn't work.

This is my Java Build Path :

- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
- Android 2.1
    -> android.jar
- Android Dependencies
    -> annotations.jar
- Junit 3
    -> junit.jar

Comment: Context may be not available in the classs path, try add its jar file in the class path.
also Context is a abstract class, you can extend it in to a anonymous class and use that...
give more detail on the error and structure.

Comment: try using EasyMock.Create instead of mock

Comment: In build path, I have :
- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
- Android 2.1 (with android.jar)
- Andoird Dependencies
- JUnit3

Normally, the class Context should be on library Android, no?

Comment: @user1836315 Are you trying to build android junit, or normal unit test, that you try to run on your workstation?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question.
I have an other test class (in the same project) witch test an other simple class which hasn't android object. I can run this test class without problem

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, Your question is if I run my class with Junit test or Android Junit test ?
For this case, I run with Junit test.
If I try to run with Android Junit test, I have the error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.Mockito

Comment: @user1836315 usually unit tests of Adnroid applications are meant to be run in a context of android device. This is why the android sdk related classes will not be automatically on your build path when you run ordinary junit tests. Thus `Context` is not recognized

Comment: OK.
I have succeed to resolve my problem by running as Android Junit test and hadding mockito-all-1.9.5.jar on a folder libs/ on my android test projet.
#  
I have a new error which ma be caused by mockito : 

    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
    ...

Answer (score 88):

Not sure if I had the same problem as you but I am using gradle and for some reason the tests just wouldn't run anymore, with the same error as you had. I tried cleaning and rebuilding but to no avail. After hours of frustration and trying to find an answer I came across the simple solution in a GitHub thread:

> I resolved this issue by **removing the .gradle folder** in my project and rebuilding the project.

(thanks to vpetrov)

Comment: Perfect. I had this problem after updating to Android Studio 2.3. Removing .gradle/ folder solves the issue.

Comment: OMG. it works. I was almost going to bang my head. Thank you. If some problem comes, first delete .gradle evil file :D

Comment: Thanks a bunch my friend

Comment: Just to make it explicit, here's what worked for me: Quit Android Studio, delete .gradle folder, open Android Studio and try again.

Answer (score 33):

You can run `./gradlew clean test` in the terminal.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, you can run this as a gradle task.

Answer (score 20):

Fixed the issue by following these steps --

1.Open module level build.gradle file, go to dependencies, go to this line --

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

2.Change the junit version to anything else below it (like 4.10)

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.10'
```

3.Sync project

4.The issue fixed at this point in my case

5.Set the junit version back to what it was before (4.12 in my case) if you want

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

6.Sync project

Changing the junit version and syncing project worked in my case.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, but what kind of voodoo is this??  What in the heck?

Comment: did not work for me. was 'junit:junit:4.13' changed 'junit:junit:4.12' synced then back to 'junit:junit:4.13' ran tests but same error

Comment: @TajuddinKhandaker Try running tests after changing to 4.12 and 4.10.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case I had to change from `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.73` to `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4`

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric version 4.4 seems not to support jdk 14. So I could switch to jdk 13 or update robolectric to  `4.5-alpha-1`