# JUnit test cases fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit, android-gradle-plugin

After updating the Gradle from 2.2.3 to 2.3.3 in android studio, all the JUnit test cases failed with the error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/Context
```

on every class initialization steps. No issues while running the application.
Can anyone please help me to solve the issue.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213219/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorandroid-and-junit-test

Comment: I removed the .gradle folder and rebuild the project, resulting in a new error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView